# How to change the permission of /dev/hugepages?

Tags: sysctl, huge-pages

I have an app that open() a file under `/dev/hugepages` to allocate a huge page.
For now, it requires root.

How can I change the permissions?

It's automatically mounted by F38 with:

```bash
#/usr/lib/systemd/system/dev-hugepages.mount

#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Huge Pages File System
Documentation=https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.html
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
ConditionPathExists=/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages
ConditionCapability=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
ConditionVirtualization=!private-users

[Mount]
What=hugetlbfs
Where=/dev/hugepages
Type=hugetlbfs
```

I tried to add this line under [Mount]:

```
Options=uid=1000
```

without luck, the permission is correct using `ls` but it just doesn't work.